# How to retrieve records which are 3 months old using Asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-access, c#-4.0

I want to pull the employee records who have joined three months back to the company, I'm using a accdb database and the coding would be asp.net c#, I always get stuck in the date and days for retrieving records.

```
 public void DisplayProbationList()
{
     DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime Threemonthago = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    //string sql = "SELECT * FROM HolidaysList";
    //command.CommandText = sql;
    OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails where Datejoining Between '"+ Threemonthago+"' AND '"+Today+"' ", connection);
    OleDbDataAdapter OleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    Probation.DataSource = ds;
    Probation.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Could you show what you've tried, e.g. the SQL code you used? Or the C# code you use to access the database, it would help if we had something to correct/help with.

Comment: I have uploaded my code.

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code ? You can do `joiningDate >= ThreeMonthsAgoDate`

Comment: Based off @ChetanRanpariya's comment, your sql could look like: `"SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails where date(Datejoining) >= '" + Threemonthago.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"`. I added the "ToString()" and "date()" to remove the time components (in most cases it should not matter though).

Comment: And I'm also getting an error as data type mismatch error in criteria expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *octothorpes* in Access SQL and a forced format of the date expressions:

```
OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails WHERE Datejoining BETWEEN #" + Threemonthago.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# AND #" + Today.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#", connection);
```

Please note that concatenation in this case is safe, as values are generated in code, thus no injection can take place. Otherwise, consider using parameters.

Comment: I expect this is safe, but isn't there a method for parameter binding, Gustav? SQL concatenation doesn't feel like a good method to encourage under any circumstances.

Comment: There is, and I would prefer it myself, and it is easy to find. You don't even have to go further than here at SO where multiple examples can be found.

Comment: OK. I apologise for the downvote, but I think high-rep users should be setting an example of best practice (especially to the OP, who probably does not know). cc @Harsha

Comment: @halfer: Sorry, saw you as the questioneer. However, while using parameters is the preferred method, here you are inserting two date values entirely created in code; it is absolutely safe to concatenate these. And please note, I just solved a trivial issue, I didn't encourage anything.

Comment: @Gustav: thanks for the reply. The problem with that is that once someone has seen SQL injection as an acceptable way to form a query, they will do it with user input too, having not been warned about the consequences.

Comment: @halfer: Yes, I know what you mean. But no injection can take place in cases where values are code generated like here. It is pure concatenation.

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem with that is that once someone has seen SQL injection as an acceptable way to form a query, they will do it with user input too, which is not safe. Perhaps you could add a note at the end of your post?

Comment: @halfer: OK. Comment added.